# Confounding NUMA configuration in SQL Server for 24 vcore system in Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, numa

I need some help understanding how SQL Server takes a 24 core VM and displays it as 11 NUMA nodes under properties.

At startup, this is the key message about hardware SQL Server found:

```
SQL Server detected 1 sockets with 7 cores per socket and 14 logical processors per socket, 24 total logical processors; using 24 logical processors based on SQL Server licensing. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
```

I do not understand how it detects 1 socket with 14 total vCores and then says it has 24 total logical processors.  Can someone help me understand that?

The VM is in Azure and is an [E96-24as_v4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/eav4-easv4-series) which is based on [AMD EPYC 7452](https://www.amd.com/en/products/cpu/amd-epyc-7452).  That CPU appears to have 32 cores for each socket of whatever Azure has it running on.

The E96-24 means it is a 96 core VM suppressed down to 24 by Azure to give a better core to memory ratio.

SQL Server shows 11 NUMA nodes with the first 2 nodes (NODE 0 and NODE 1) with 3 vCores and the remaining nodes with 2 vCores each.

The workload on this server is OLAP/DSS.

Soft NUMA is off.

As requested in comments here is the output from os_nodes and os_memory_nodes:

| osn.node_id | osn.online_scheduler_count | osn.cpu_count | osn.memory_node_id | osmn.target_kb | osn.processor_group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3 | 3 | 0 | 60023896 | 0 |
| 1 | 3 | 3 | 1 | 60023896 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 60023896 | 0 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 60023896 | 0 |
| 4 | 2 | 2 | 4 | 60023896 | 0 |
| 5 | 2 | 2 | 5 | 60023896 | 0 |
| 6 | 2 | 2 | 6 | 60023896 | 0 |
| 7 | 2 | 2 | 7 | 60023896 | 0 |
| 8 | 2 | 2 | 8 | 60023896 | 0 |
| 9 | 2 | 2 | 9 | 60023896 | 0 |
| 10 | 2 | 2 | 10 | 60023896 | 0 |

Comment: Can you post the results set from this query? SELECT osn.node_id, osn.online_scheduler_count, osn.cpu_count
     , osn.memory_node_id, osmn.target_kb, osn.processor_group
FROM sys.dm_os_nodes osn
JOIN sys.dm_os_memory_nodes osmn
ON osn.memory_node_id = osmn.memory_node_id
WHERE node_state_desc = 'ONLINE';

Comment: @sqL_handLe - I updated the post with the requested content.

Comment: ok, just about ready to write an answer.  the virtual socket configuration certainly is unexpected; what will likely have more of an impact on performnce and behavior in the SQL Server instance is the surprisingly high number of NUMA nodes and that they don't all have the same vcore count.  Two more questions related to stuff i'll put in the answer: 1) do you have access to the OS to run logman & perfmon? 2) could you execute DBCC TRACESTATUS to indicate if any trace flags are enabled?

Comment: I do have OS access.  It is a VM built from a Microsoft image of SQL Server from the Azure marketplace.   No meaningful modifications made to SQL Server or the VM. 
 
Results of DBCC TRACESTATUS show no traces:

DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.

Completion time: 2021-02-23T06:10:53.1023337+00:00

Comment: Just came to say I have the exact same question! I found this resource, suggesting that azure configured it with 'numa-per-core' https://developer.amd.com/wp-content/resources/56782_1.0.pdf